# Bounded real analytic function with bounded derivative and its higher order derivatives

Tags: analytic-functions

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a bounded analytic function such that its derivative is also bounded. What kind of bound can we get on the higher order derivatives of $f$? Does it follow that they are bounded as well?

Comment: in general you can get bounds for the in-between derivatives from the outer ones (in other words bounds for $f, f^{(n)}$ give bounds for $f',..f^{(n-1)}, n \ge 2$; this comes under the Landau-Kolmogorov inequalities heading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_inequality

Comment: Thank you, Conrad! That's really interesting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, $f(x)=\int_0^x \sin t^2\, dt$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you, Christian!